# Simulate text decoration color for text decoration line through

Tags: css, cross-browser

I have read that text-decoration-color is not supported for major browser, so my question is the following -- **Is there a way yo simulate the text-decoration-color?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a couple of ways.

I prefer the pseudo-element...it's much more controllable and animatable than just a border.

```css
a {
  color: red;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.border {
  border-bottom: 2px solid green;
}
.pseudo {
  position: relative;
}
.pseudo::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: blue;
}
.anim::after {
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: transform .5s ease;
}
.anim:hover::after {
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
.strike::after {
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<a class="border" href="#">I'm decorated</a>

<a class="pseudo" href="#">I'm also decorated</a>

<a class="pseudo anim" href="#">I'm also animated on hover</a>


<a class="pseudo strike" href="#">I'm lined through</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `text-decoration` styling does have [horrible browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=text-decoration).

For the different `text-decoration` values:

### `text-decoration:underline;`:

Simply use a `border-bottom` instead of `text-decoration`:

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://example.com">Examples</a>
```

This might not have the exact effect, but quite similar.

### `text-decoration:overline;`:

Simply use a `border-top` instead of `text-decoration`:

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  border-top: 1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://example.com">Examples</a>
```

### `text-decoration:line-through;`:

Not as simple, for this we have to use pseudo elements:

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}
a:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 1px;
  background: orange;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://example.com">Examples</a>
```

The above aligns the line in the vertical middle of the element. Note that the `<a>` can only be single lined for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, depending on your usecase (if you only have text in a single line) you could use a pseudo-element and position and color it.

html:

`<p>Lorem Ipsum <a href="#">Dolor</a> Sit amet</p>`

css:

```
a {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  height: 1px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Myyzwx

however, if the affected element (word-)breaks this will lead to unwanted behaviour